# Как захватить изображение окна игры средствами java?

Tags: java

Есть задача: сделать скриншот окна игры (не известно, directx, или opengl), чтобы потом обрабатывать его. На c# я делал это через winapi, получая hwid окна по его имени (при этом изображение получалось, даже если окно было перекрыто другим окном). Выглядело это как-то так:

```
internal static Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();

    PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);

    gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
    gfxBmp.Dispose();

    return bmp;
}
```

Интересно, могу ли я как-то сделать это в java (возможно, другим способом). Получение окна из обычного скриншота экрана не интересно. Если решение будет еще и кроссплатформенным, будет вообще замечательно.

Comment: Я уже нашел, что это принципиально возможно с помощью winapi, те же [PrintWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433994/java-window-image) и [GetWindowRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039386/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-specified-applet-or-program-in-java), но меня все еще интересуют кроссплатформенные решения, либо отдельные решения для mac и linux